# How to use attributed string as navigation bar title in iOS 5.0?

Tags: ios, ios5

Is there any way to use attributed label on navigation bar on iOS 5? I know it works in iOS 6+ but before that?
I want to use both bold and non bold font there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that helped me:

```
 // Total string
    NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@ %@ %@", gameName, stringConnector, self.bet.gameInfo.draw.drawNumber, stringConnector2,  [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.bet.gameInfo.draw.date]];

    NSRange range = [tempString rangeOfString:gameName];

    NSMutableAttributedString * string2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:tempString];

    // font for all string
    UIFont *regularFont = [UIFont fontWithName:BEAU_PRO_LIGHT_FONT_NAME size:21];
    CTFontRef font_2 = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)regularFont.fontName, regularFont.pointSize, NULL);
    [string2 addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)font_2 range:[tempString rangeOfString:tempString]];

    // bold font
    UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:BEAU_PRO_SEMIBOLD_FONT_NAME size:21];
    CTFontRef font_1 = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)boldFont.fontName, boldFont.pointSize, NULL);
    [string2 addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)font_1 range:range];

    TTTAttributedLabel * label = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 20)];
    label.attributedText = string2;
    [label sizeToFit];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [TTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) to achieve this. Here is the code to do the trick. Suppose you want to set title to "Sample NavBarTitle" where the Sample should bold.

```
//In your code there may be several ranges, corresponding to how many attributes you want to have
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 6);
//Initialize NSMutableAttributedString
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Sample NavBarTitle"];
//Set the attribute to make "Sample" bold
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-Bold" size:15] range:range];
//Initialize TTAttributedLabel with rect
TTTAttributedLabel * label = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 150)];
//Set the attributedText property of TTAttributedLabel
label.attributedText = string;
//Set navigationItem.titleView to the label view we've created
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

That's all.

Comment: This looks good but NSFontAttributeName is ios6 only enum. What can I use instead?

Comment: @Dvole This answer answers your question pretty well, so please, accept it. And if you are interested in `NSFontAttributeName` like thing for other iOS versions, add new question, or edit your current question to include that.

Comment: @FahriAzimov not really, it crashes in iOS 5.

Comment: Try using kCTFontAttributeName, if it doesn't work either, I'll try to provide another solution.